# For Wordpress's plugin (All-in-One Event Calendar), how do you display the event date in a different format?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want something like this to show up on the page: Jan 29 Mon 2-9 pm

I can't use `<?php get_timespan_html(); ?>` as it would display something like "July 13, 2013 @ 1:00 pm – 3:00 pm."

I also tried

```
<?php echo date_i18n( 'M', $timestamp, true ) ?>
<?php echo date_i18n( 'j', $timestamp, true ) ?>
<?php echo date_i18n( 'D', $timestamp, true ) ?>
<?php echo $event->get_start_time(); ?> – <?php echo $event->get_end_time(); ?>
```

but for some reason it only displays Jan 1 Thu 1:00 pm – 3:00 pm for each event instead of the correct event information.

Help?

plugin link: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/all-in-one-event-calendar

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer!

Go [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90939/all-in-one-event-calendar-custom-query-getting-each-event-instance) and skip to the answer. So happy the problem is solved :)